# document.body.insertBefore doesn't work

Tags: javascript

In the following html page i try to put script2 before footer. But this doesn't work. What's wrong?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>scrollLeft demo</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script>
    var script2 = document.createElement('script');
    script2.text="alert('ΟΚ')";
    document.body.insertBefore( script2, document.getElementsByClassName('footer'));
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="demo"><h1>lalala</h1><p>Hello</p></div>
<div class="footer"><p>hello</p><p>world</p></div>

</body>
</html>
```

I also tried

```
 document.head.appendChild(script2);
```

which works and

```
 document.body.appendChild(script2);
```

which doesn't work!

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` , `footer` is a class, not a tag name. You should wrap your code in a domready function , like `$(function(){ ... }); ` then the code will be executed when the DOM has been parsed and you will be able to update the body content

Comment: Why do you want to place it before the `.footer`?

Comment: Hacketo you're right. I wanted to write getElementsByClassName.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is, document.body is not defined yet, it hasn't even started loading when the javascript is interpreted

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems with this.

You first need to make sure that you are running the javascript at the correct time. In your code, you are running the JS before the body tag is read. Instead place the `<script>` before the closing `</body>` tag.

Also, the `insertBefore()` function takes `newNode` and `referenceNode` as parameters. `document.getElementsByTagName('footer')` returns a list of elements. Instead, change it to `document.getElementsByTagName('footer')[0]` to retrun the 1st element in the list

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found it. This is the correct. I put it inside document.ready as Jaromanda X suggested and I add ('footer')[0] as Jackson suggested:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   var script2 = document.createElement('script');
   script2.text="alert('ΟΚ')";
   document.body.insertBefore( script2, document.getElementsByClassName('footer')[0]);
});
```